# Knapsack with weight and item limit

Tags: algorithm, knapsack-problem

if I have a knapsack with weight limit W, item Limit K and I have N items, N >= k

I know how to maximize it in by having a 3 dimensional memorization array m[N][W][K] (N items to consider, W weight left, K items left to choose from) and thus do it in O(N * W * K) complexity but is there way to do it even faster in a 2 dimensional memorization array and achieve a faster complexity, something like O(N * W) complexity?

Comment: What would be the model of the two-dimensional dynamic programming (or memoization)? As far as I know, there is no canonical way of reducing runtime complexity by simply eliminating axes of a dynamic programming formulation.

Comment: My feeling this that there is no straightforward way to optimize this. Of course you could generally use a better knapsack algorithm.

Comment: Example of a better algorithm, at least when the profitability of items varies somewhat: branch and bound (where the bound comes from solving the dual linear program).

Answer (score 1):

The memoization you are using is not correct: "m[N][W][K] (N items to consider, W weight left, K items left to choose from)". It does not capture the complete information of which items are left to choose from versus how many items are left to choose from.

The problem you are trying to solve is the [Multi dimensional knapsack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Multi-dimensional_knapsack_problem), which is more complex than the classic problem.